# Oracle SQL Group by and compare subsets

Tags: sql, oracle, subset

Consider following table,
+-----+----------+
| ID  | VALUE |
+-----+----------+
|  1  |      A  |
|  1  |      B  |
|  2  |      A  |
|  2  |      B  |
|  2  |      C  |
|  3  |      A  |
|  3  |      C  |
|  4  |      A  |
|  4  |      F  |
|  4  |      B  |
+-----+----------+
I need to get ID which have all the values in ID = 1; That mean what are the IDs Having Value A and B(both)
Expected IDs : 1, 2 , 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.id
from t join
     t t1
     on t1.id = 1 and t1.value = t.value
group by t.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.id = 1);
```

The self-join matches on the values, keeping only rows that match the `id = 1` values.  The `having` counts the number of matches, to see if all values are included for a given `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be counting A's and B's within groups:

```
with t (id, value) as (
    select 1, 'A' from dual union
    select 1, 'B' from dual union
    select 2, 'A' from dual union
    select 2, 'B' from dual union
    select 2, 'C' from dual union
    select 3, 'A' from dual union
    select 3, 'C' from dual union
    select 4, 'A' from dual union
    select 4, 'F' from dual union
    select 4, 'B' from dual 
)
select id from t group by id
having sum(decode(value,'A',1,0)) > 0
   and sum(decode(value,'B',1,0)) > 0;
```